# Emacs fails to open gnuplot files with extension .gp

Tags: osx

May I get some help understanding what it is that Emacs does not like about the extension `.gp`

- Using emacs 24.5.2 on Mac OS X 10.13.6
- I get the following error message when I try to open a file with extension .gp.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Cannot open load file" "no such file or directory" "gnuplot")
  gnuplot-mode()
  set-auto-mode-0(gnuplot-mode nil)
  set-auto-mode()
  normal-mode(t)
  after-find-file(nil t)
  find-file-noselect-1(#<buffer gpiofl.gp> "~/gpiofl.gp" nil nil "~/gpiofl.gp" (8739733818 16777220))
  find-file-noselect("/Users/cizmas/gpiofl.gp" nil nil nil)
  find-file("/Users/cizmas/gpiofl.gp")
  command-line-1(("gpiofl.gp"))
  command-line()
```

- In this case, the file name is `gpiofl.gp`.  If I change the extension to `.gnuplot`, all is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(file-error "Cannot open load file" "no such file or directory" "gnuplot")` means that it was looking for `gnuplot.el` or `gnuplot.elc`, but couldn't find it. It was doing this because it was trying to call the function `gnuplot-mode` in order to activate Gnuplot mode. Are you sure that Gnuplot mode is actually installed? It sounds like you have associated it with files named `*.gp` in your init file, but have not actually installed the Gnuplot mode's code correctly.

To check whether the `gnuplot-mode` library is installed, you can say `M-x locate-library RET gnuplot-mode RET`.

See the [github page](https://github.com/emacsorphanage/gnuplot) for installation instructions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am not sure whether Gnuplot mode is installed. How can I check whether it is installed or not? If it is not installed, how can I install it?